# Keyboard shortcut mapping for Ctrl+Alt+Del in Parallels

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

I'm a Windows user with a Windows-oriented keyboard, and I switched the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys in OSX, because I want to use the same keyboard shortcuts whether in Windows or OSX.  This came back to haunt me though when I installed a Windows VM in Parallels, and it broke the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combo to login to Windows in the VM (since the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is mapped to <kbd>Command</kbd>).  I would like to create a shortcut mapping <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to the Parallels menu item Devices -> Keyboard -> Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but the shortcuts section of System Preferences -> Keyboard does not allow me to use the <kbd>Del</kbd> key.

I tried following the instructions in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108248/87011), adding this:

```
<key>Ctrl+Alt+Delete</key>
<string>@~&#x7f;</string>
```

to each of

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.parallels.Parallels.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.parallels.Parallels Desktop.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.parallels.desktop.console.plist
```

but the key combo is not activating the menu item to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> when adding the XML to any of those.

What am I doing wrong here?  Do I need something special to activate the options in the "keyboard" submenu of "Device"?  Do I have the wrong code for the <kbd>Del</kbd> key?  Am I putting the XML in the wrong plist file(s)?

**[Edit]**

The problem is worse than I thought, because the keys stay switched in Windows.  Is there a way to set the modifier key behavior on a per-application basis?  It would be great if I could swap the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys generally, and swap them back in Parallels.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an answer to the base question, but I did locate a sufficiently good workaround.  [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) offers finer-grained control of keys than OSX's keyboard settings, including the ability to add exceptions to key switching.  I used these settings:

```
Karabiner -> Change Key
    Change Command_L Key -> Command_L to Control_L (except Virtual Machine, RDC)
    Change Control_L Key -> Control_L to Command_L (except Virtual Machine, RDC)
```

Now all of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keyboard shortcuts I am accustomed to work in both OSX and my VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been able to perform the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combo functionality in Parallels using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. As far as I know this is default functionality (based on the fact that I did not play around with the key mappings in Parallels, and this key combo has always worked for me).

However, I don't know if remapping the keys or playing around with Parallels' settings has broken that functionality for you...

Currently, I am using Mac OSX Mavericks with Parallels Desktop 8 (haven't bothered upgrading to 9 yet, though I doubt they would have changed this functionality).

**[Edit]**

To address your edit: The <kbd>Command</kbd> key seems to have a double functionality of both being the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> keys in Parallels (or at least on my Mac it does... This may be an option I turned on in Parallels' options). However, it has a preference for being the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key.

Therefore, in Parallels using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will both copy, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will both paste.

Alternatively, using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will show the desktop in Parallels, the way that pressing <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does on a regular Windows PC.

However, keep in mind that, as mentioned above, <kbd>Command</kbd> has a preference for being the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key.

Here is an example of where that may come into play:
On a regular Windows PC, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> can be used to search in a program, while <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the shortcut key to find in files.
Therefore, in Parallels, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> can be used to search in a program, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the shortcut key to find in files.

Comment: Using OSX's modifier key remapping screws up a bunch of that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with the new Karabiner Elements version (Sierra upwards) it would be easiest to temporarily "Quit K E" via its menu bar icon or to create a second "Profile" (K-E tab) which contains only rules/modifications you need in Parallels.
Can be toggled in menu bar.

No tweaking, twitching or honky-tonky … ;-)